# android jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am working on android project and my web service successfully giving response in postman as I mention response below. I am getting below error after getting response from my API. I am not doing this types of web service call first time but don't know why this happening. How can I achieve this ?

web service response in postman -

```
[
    {
        "emp_id": 43065,
        "emp_name": "Rahul Bhandari",
        "username": "43065",
        "password": null
    }
]
```

Error -

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"emp_id":43065,"emp_name":"Rahul Bhandari","username":"43065","password":null}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Volley Code -

```
public void apiCall(final String email, final String password) {
        processArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.login, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        if (mStatusCode == 200) {
                            try {
                                loginResult = new JSONArray(response.toString());


                                try {
                                    if (loginResult != null) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < loginResult.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject obj = loginResult.getJSONObject(i);
                                            // SQLite database handler
                                            db = new SQLiteHandler(LoginActivity.this);
                                            // Session manager
                                            session = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
                                            session.setLogin(true);
                                            // Inserting row in users table
                                            db.addUser(obj.getString("username"), obj.getString("emp_name"), obj.getString("emp_id"), obj.getString("emp_designation"), obj.getString("emp_location"));

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SelectAuditActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish();

                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfull login...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credential...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //Process os success response
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Oops sorry something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        //Process os success response
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
        };
        ;

        // add the request object to the queue to be executed
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is a json array

```
[
{
    "emp_id": 43065,
    "emp_name": "Rahul Bhandari",
    "username": "43065",
    "password": null
}
]
```

but you are making `JsonObjectRequest` , do a `JsonArrayRequest`  instead

**EDIT:**

I see you post body is a Json object and you cannot directly send a Json object in `JsonArrayRequest` , so you have to send the body using `getBody()` method

example request

```
  JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (requestMethod, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //do some thing with response
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  //  handelErrorResponse
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return setHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {

               String body;
             // convert your json object to string and send it
               body= yourJsonobject.toString();

                return body.getBytes();

        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            getHeader(response);
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   JsonArrayRequest request_json = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.login, new JSONArray(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
```

I think you have to replace JsonObjectRequest with JsonArrayRequest once try replacing them like above i did not tried  this but hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

These square brackets `[ {...}, {...},.. ]` represent for a JSONArray. So if your array have only one items, Change `JsonObjectRequest` to `JsonArrayRequest` which will return an JSONArray then get the first item from this array.

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JSONObject result = response.get(0);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a request using the object `JsonObjectRequest`, this mean that your request are expecting a json in the object format like:

```
{ a: "a", b: "b" }
```

but your service is responding with a json array that look like:

```
[{a:"a", b:"b"} , {a:"a1", b:"b1"}]
```

so, in order to get rid of your error change the way you make your request using `JsonArrayRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
if (loginResult != null) {
        //for (int i = 0; i < loginResult.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject obj = loginResult.getJSONObject(0);
             //JSONObject obj = loginResult.getJSONObject(i);
             // SQLite database handler
              db = new SQLiteHandler(LoginActivity.this);
              // Session manager
             session = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
             session.setLogin(true);
            // Inserting row in users table

            /*db.addUser(obj.getString("username"), obj.getString("emp_name"), obj.getString("emp_id"), obj.getString("emp_designation"), obj.getString("emp_location"));*/

             db.addUser(obj.getString("username"), obj.getString("emp_name"), obj.getString("emp_id"),"","");

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SelectAuditActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfull login...", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             //}
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credential...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

return this only from web services

```
{
        "emp_id": 43065,
        "emp_name": "Rahul Bhandari",
        "username": "43065",
        "password": null
    }
```

Comment: onResponse() accept JsonObject but you are accepting json array from web services.